# Why does subversion always include one file in my commit?

Tags: svn, netbeans

I am using subversion via NetBenas 7 to maintain my source code.  No problems so far until I somehow created this one file that is always included in the commit even though I never change it.  In the commit dialog box its status is always marked as "Up To Date."   I have to manually un-check it each time I do a commit.   No other file in the project acts like this.

As far as I know this hasn't caused me any real problem, but it is annoying and possibly an indication of some deeper problem.   Can anyone tell how this could have happened and how to fix it?

### update

I am beginning to think this is a Netbeans wrapper problem and not svn at all.  I have the same project on both my iMac at home and my laptop at work.  Both are using the same version of Netbeans.  When I do a check-in from the laptop, it doesn't add this odd file to the commit -- when I do from the iMac it does.

However I can't find anything in Netbeans that flags the odd file as anything different from normal.   I am going to try removing the file from the project and we'll see if that solves it.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: "This one file" - One file to rule them all.. Which file are we talking about here?

Comment: `svn status` output or `svn diff filename`?

Comment: @halfdan :  specifically, just a file in ./src/main/webapp/resources/qc  There are 10 files in that directory.  It is just an xhtml file.

Comment: @LazyBadger both svn diff tallySummaryVertical.xhtml 
and svn status tallySummaryVertical.xhtml both generate no output.  I am not too familiar with the svn command line interface.  Too dependent on Netbeans.   I am beginning to think this is a Netbeans problem and not svn at all.

Comment: `diff -c <your last revision id> tallySummaryVertical.xhtml` ???

Answer (score 1):

Is this file added or modified in svn? If it is added then undo add. If it is modified then compare it with latest version in svn. If you want to undo changes then revert the file to latest version in svn.

Comment: @Dialectius It was added and then modified many revisions ago.   I am on about revision 190 and the last time that file was revised was about 154.  When I do a commit the dialog box shows the status as either "Locally New" or "Locally Modified."   This one and only this one always says "Up to date."

Comment: It says up to date, okay. But maybe dialog is somehow wrong. Is the file different from latest version in svn? If it is identical, then try to revert it to set the dialog straight. Or try to delete it physically, and revert then. Or try to commit it (if there are no changes then nothing should be commited, but the goal is to smack the dialog out of hallucinations).